# Google Auth auto logs in

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Google sign in to my mobile application, however, it asked me once for my e-mail and password. When I run the app again it skips the login screen and automatically navigates to the home screen.

I tried:
Deleting the app on the menu.
Clearing the cache on settings. (I guess I couldn't do it properly not for sure)
Even deleted the profile which automatically logs in. (still holds this profile as user idk how...)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './components/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'components/body.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import '../home/home_screen.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context);
                  if (provider.isSigningIn) {
                    return buildLodading();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print("data: ${snapshot.data}");
                    return HomeScreen();
                  } else {
                    return Body();
                  }
                })));
  }

  Widget buildLodading() => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Body() = The login screen.

The program always returns true on snapshot.hasData so that it doesn't go in else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the expected behavior. When you restart the app, Firebase implicitly tries to restore the user credentials, so that the user doesn't have to sign in each time they start the app.

If you want the user to explicitly require the user to provide their sign-in credentials each time they start the app, sign any existing user out when the app starts.

For example:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  runApp(App());
}
```